# Crystal Reports 13 Group Duplicates

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report that is showing duplicates in groups but not in "ungrouped" order.

I have the data grouped as follows: SKU-->Receipt#-->TransactionDate. Within the TransactionDate group, I have PalletID. My problem is, when the report is **ungrouped**, the PalletID is not duplicated. However, since there are multiple transactions for some PalletIDs, when I **group** the duplicates are displayed. Is there a way I can only show the oldest transaction for each PalletID when grouping?

Before suppressing:

[image: Pre-Suppress]

After suppressing:

[image: Post-Suppress]

I will eventually suppress the group details to only display group totals.

Comment: Can you add more information? Maybe a screenshot of your issue if you can, or some more in depth explanation about your scenario and what you expect to happen?

Comment: I updated my post to include a photo. Preferably I would like to eliminate the following when data is suppressed and only have the earliest date display.  
40500448           
10710           
9/20/2019           
           
9/21/2019